# (Update)Using a bidirectional optocoupler for attaching any PNP & NPN sensor type

Tags: opto-isolator, npn, pnp, proximity-sensor, bidirectional

I have two different 12 V PNP & NPN proximity sensors. My first design was for each sensor type, having an identical PCB design with a normal optocoupler with a dedicated wiring arrangement.

My question is: can I use a bidirectional optocoupler for attaching any PNP & NPN sensor type to the same PCB?

If so, how can I add VSS and VDD of the input sensor to such a bidirectional optocoupler?

Update
I think using 2 opts would be a better option, however, I'm not sure whether the output signals can show the signal for each sensor type because if any opt is not active it goes pullup or pulldown while the other should show the pulse.

The current design with two input sensors.

[image]

Design with single input sensor.
[image]

Updated schematic.

[image]

New update3.

[image]

Comment: The second design will instantly burn out the optoisolator's LEDs.

Comment: @vir is there any wrong with the wiring or my idea wrong

Comment: You have the optoisolator LEDs connected in series directly between 12V and ground.  You will need separate circuits to drive each one if you want to go that way.

Comment: @vir is this new schematic correct ?

Comment: What’s the purpose of Q2?

Comment: @winny ; A microcontroller can detect any rasing or falling voltage, my idea is to use the hardware to convert this change to MCU voltage level and by firmware set which NPN or PNP sensor use then enable MCU pin pull-up or pull-down function

Comment: Please simulate it. Then remove Q2 and simulate again.

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNW7Dw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Not especially elegant, and you will need to adjust R1 and R2 to the specs of your optocoupler and expected drop across the transistor in the sensor, but if you can live with losing a few mW in the voltage divider, this should work.

Comment: can you please check my design

Comment: how can I add these schematics to the 2 optocoupler?

Comment: this is basically the same circuit as Hamid has drawn,

Comment: @Jasen I updated the sematic using the pull-push BJT

Comment: that looks much worse... stick with the first one,