# Using bidirectional optocoupler instead of two identical optocoupler

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, opto-isolator, proximity-sensor, bidirectional

I have two types of PNP & NPN proximity sensors and intend to use one connection socket for both types.
I design a circuit with two normal optos for each line however to save the parts and space I intend to use a one-directional opto for both sensors.

My question is do these two circuits provide the same functionality?

2 optos design:
[image]

1 bi-di opto design:

[image]

Comment: Hamid s k - Hi, This looks like the next stage of your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/606994) and should not have been posted as a new question. However, now you have answers on that question and this one, so neither can be deleted. The least bad option that I can see, is to close the "old" question as a duplicate of this one, so that no-one adds new answers on that old question. Please do *not* ask yet another version of this topic, *especially* without explaining how it is different from the others and if any other related question is still open. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson the previous question was about using 3 pins while this question use 4 pin which makes it a very different scenario from the last one

Comment: Hamid s k - Hi, Since this question is clearly related to your previous one, then it is your responsibility to make things clear for readers. For the future, I recommend that if a similar situation happens, you should include a clear explanation in *both* questions of why you need to ask a 2nd question & explain in each question the details of how it is different from the other one(s). In general, you should not have more than one open question, at the same time, on related topics - otherwise it becomes confusing and readers are more likely to flag them as (near) duplicates, as happened here.

Answer (score 2):

**2 optos design**:

[image]

*Figure 1. One channel of the original circuit (which has now been updated in the question).*

1. OK8 and OK10 will never turn on because D6 and D8 are installed backwards and will limit the voltage on the LEDs to 0.7 V.
2. An NPN switch requires a pull-up. You haven't got one.
3. A PNP switch requires a pull-down. You haven't got one.

**1 bi-di opto design**:

[image]

*Figure 2. The bi-directional opto design.*

1. You've drawn it upside-down with ground symbols pointing up and V+ at the bottom. This makes it difficult to see what's going on.
2. D3 is behaving like a regular diode and will clamp PNP_PRX to 0.7 V maximum. It seems to be in backwards.
3. As drawn, current will flow from +12V through D4 (dropping 5.2 V), through R8, up through OK6, through R7 and via D3 to AGND. You'll have about 6 V across R8, OK6 and R7. With 1.4 V dropped across the IR LED you'll have \$ I = \frac {12 - 5.2 -1.4 - 0.7} {360 + 360} = 6.5\ \mathrm{mA} \$ through the LED. This will be enough to turn the opto-transistor on.
4. A PNP prox switch will do nothing while off but pull R5 high when on. Any current through R5 will go to AGND through D3. The opto-output will remain on.
5. Similarly an NPN switch on pin 2 will pull R6 low but the voltage an NPN_PRX will not change because it is held at 6.8 V by D4.

This won't work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5IwGk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 3. Common method of PLC input module configuration for NPN and PNP inputs.*

SW1 is usually a 3-pin header with a 2-pin jumper or else a screw terminal in common with the other inputs and is wired to V+ or COM depending on the sensors being used.

Component count reduced from seven to two.

Comment: An NPN switch doesn't require a pull-up if all it's doing is driving a high-side LED. Similarly a PNP doesn't require a pull-down to drive a low-side LED. Agree with everything else though.

Comment: Yes, but as drawn and labelled by the OP they do and the logic will be inverted.

Comment: Oh - yeah - I didn't read the labels on the schematic and just assume that OK7, etc  was for the NPN and OK8, etc was for the PNP (because that way would have made sense ...).

Comment: tnx @Transistor for your comments, it seems you are not in favor of bi-opts caz it needs an extra jumper. I update the circuit regards to your comments

Comment: (1) "*...  it seems you are not in favor of bi-opts caz it needs an extra jumper.*" I **am** in favour of the circuit of Figure 3. (2) "*I update the circuit regards to your comments.*" Be careful with edits. If you change the question you make the answers look stupid. You should **add** the new schematic and leave the old one there so the answer makes sense. I have added the original schematic. (3) On your new schematic you would need to connect NPN to pin 3 and PNP to pin 2. Your labels are wrong. (4) You don't need the Zener diodes. 1k of resistance will limit to about 10 mA @ 12 V.

Comment: ... Note how much easier it is to read a well-cropped schematic image.

Comment: @Transistor you're totally right, my mistake;1: I use these proximity sensors for measuring the RPM and they have internal pull-up and pull-down, does need extra pull-up-pull-down?2: if swape the labels does make the circuit correct ?:3 I add Zener diode for surge protection that may happen in the CAN bus link

Comment: (1) If the sensors have internal pull-up and pull-down then you would need to take that into consideration in your design. There is no sensor datasheet link in your question so I can't comment on that. (2) If you swap the labels then it should work. (3) How will diodes on the sensor side of the opto-isolator give protection on the CAN side (which I presume in on the output side of the opto-isolators)?